# Trouble in finding equation with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

> Let $\;f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m\;$ and $\;W:\mathbb R^m
>  \rightarrow \mathbb R_{+}\;$ two functions.
>
> We'll denote $\;f_{x_i}=(f^1_{x_i},\dots,f^m_{x_i})\;\;\forall 1\le
>  i\le n\;$ where $\;f^j_{x_i}=\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial
>  x_i}\;\;\forall 1\le i\le n,1\le j\le m\;$.
>
> Furthermore assume the $\;n \times n\;$ matrix $\;A=(a_{ij})_{1\le
>  i,j\le n}\;$ with $\;a_{ij}=f_{x_i}\cdot f_{x_j} -{\delta}_{ij}(\frac
>  {1}{2} {\vert \nabla f \vert}^2+W(f))\;$ where $\;\cdot \;$ stands for
>   the Euclidean inner product and $\;\vert \cdot \vert \;$ is the
>   Euclidean norm of the matrix.
>
> Prove that $\;A+((\frac {1}{2} {\vert \nabla f \vert}^2+W(f))I=(\nabla
>  f)^T(\nabla f)$

I'm pretty sure this "exercise" is quite easy but I miss something here. It is obvious that is sufficient to show $\;(\nabla f)^T(\nabla f)\;$ follows from $\;f_{x_i}\cdot f_{x_j}\;$ but I have no clue how to proceed.

With the above notation, all I can see is $\;(\nabla f)^T(\nabla f)=\begin{pmatrix}
    f_{x_1}\\
    \;\cdot\\
    \;\cdot\\
    f_{x_n}\\
    \end{pmatrix} ({f_{x_1}}^T, \dots, {f_{x_n}}^T)\;$

**Does this somehow connect to $\;f_{x_i}\cdot f_{x_j}\;$?**

Maybe what I'm asking is trivial, but I've no broad experience with matrices so I apologize in advance!

Any help would be valuable. Hints are also welcome!

Thanks

Comment: $(\nabla f)^T$ is a horizontal vector, with same components as $\nabla f$. The multiplication "row by column" gives the dot product

Comment: @GCab Why is $\;(\nabla f)^T\;$ a horizontal vector? By the above notation, I see it's a vertical one.$\;(\nabla f)^T= \begin{pmatrix}
    f_{x_1}\\
    \;\cdot\\
    \;\cdot\\
    f_{x_n}\\
    \end{pmatrix}\;$, isn't it?

Comment: Of course, you may be right: it's a matter of definition. But then with your interpretation $(\nabla f)^T(\nabla f)$ would be a matrix (again, unless you define the product differently than the classical "row per column").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction between whether the gradient is a row or a column vector, as well as the shape of the Jacobian, is sometimes confusing. See:

- [Gradient and Jacobian row and column conventions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336640/gradient-and-jacobian-row-and-column-conventions)
- [The Gradient as a Row vs. Column Vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54355/the-gradient-as-a-row-vs-column-vector)

However, usually its relatively immaterial. Note also that $ u^Tv=u\cdot v $ for vectors $u,v$.

Let $W:\mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R_{+}$, $ f:\mathbb{R}^n→\mathbb{R}^m $, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. I'll write $ f_{x_i}=\partial_i f=(\partial_i f_1 ,\ldots, \partial_i f_n) $.

I would write the "gradient" here as a row vector of column vectors:
$$ \nabla f = [\partial_1 f,\ldots, \partial_n f] = 
\begin{bmatrix} \partial_1 f_1 & \cdots & \partial_n f_1\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \partial_1 f_m & \cdots & \partial_n f _m \end{bmatrix} \in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n} $$

We then get $ (\nabla f)^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m} $, so 
$ (\nabla f)^T(\nabla f) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} $. We can then see the following:
\begin{align}
(\nabla f)^T(\nabla f) &= \begin{bmatrix}(\partial_1 f)^T \\ \vdots \\ (\partial_n f)^T\end{bmatrix}[\partial_1 f,\ldots, \partial_n f]\\[2mm]
&= \begin{bmatrix} 
(\partial_1 f)^T\partial_1 f & \cdots & (\partial_1 f)^T\partial_n f\\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
(\partial_n f)^T\partial_1 f & \cdots & (\partial_n f)^T\partial_n f  \end{bmatrix} \\[2mm]
&= \begin{bmatrix} 
\partial_1 f\cdot\partial_1 f & \cdots & \partial_1 f\cdot \partial_n f\\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
\partial_n f\cdot\partial_1 f & \cdots & \partial_n f\cdot\partial_n f  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
so the matrix has components $[(\nabla f)^T(\nabla f)]_{ij}=\partial_i f\cdot \partial_j f $. Let $c=|\nabla f|^2/2 + W(f)$.

So then we can write:
$$
A + cI = \begin{bmatrix} 
\partial_1 f\cdot\partial_1 f - c +c & \cdots & \partial_1 f\cdot \partial_n f\\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
\partial_n f\cdot\partial_1 f & \cdots & \partial_n f\cdot\partial_n f -c+c \end{bmatrix}=(\nabla f)^T(\nabla f)
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed to solve it earlier today but I'm glad to see my answer it's the same as yours. Guess the key here is $\;u^Tv=u\cdot v\;$ for $\;u,v\;$ vectors...

Comment: @kaithkolesidou Glad to help :)